# Prove that $K$ is compact

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that K is a compact subset of the complete metric space $(l^{\infty}, ||\cdot||)$ where $$K=\left\{x\equiv(x_1, x_2,...) \mid 0 \leq x_k \leq \frac{1}{k}\right\}.$$

Proof: Let $\{U_i | i \in I\}$ be an open cover such that $K \subset \bigcup U_i$. 
I need to show that there is a finite subcover.

How do i use this idea that the metric space is complete in other to find a finite subcover $U_{i_n}$

any idea that will be great thanks

Comment: What is $k$? ${}$

Comment: You can use the Heine-Borel theorem for metric spaces: In a complete metric space, a set is compact if and only if it is closed and totally bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x^n$ be a sequence in $K$. Then $(x^n_i)_n$ is a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ for each $i$. By a diagonalization argument, we may assume by passing to a subsequence that $(x^n_i)_n$ is a convergent sequence for all $i$, say $x^n_i \to x^\infty_i$. Clearly $x^\infty \in K$ and we claim $x^n \to x^\infty$ in $l^\infty$. Indeed, for any $\epsilon > 0$, choose $N$ so large that $\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$. Then we may choose $N_1$ so large that for all $n \geq N_1$ we have $|x^n_i - x^\infty_i| < \epsilon$ for all $i\leq N$. Then for all $n \geq N_1$ we have $|x^n_i - x^\infty_i|$ for all $i$, hence $||x^n - x^\infty||_\infty < \epsilon$. The conclusion follows.

Comment: how does this show that there exist a finite subcover for K

Comment: $l^\infty$ is a normed space (metric space is enough), so compactness of $K$ is equivalent to the statement that every sequence in $K$ has a subsequence which converges to an element of $K$.